# Regular expression to search a string from the data

Tags: regex

I have following set of data.Using regular expression i need to search strings `'failed','undefined'` strings inside  `steps ()`

in the current data it is `steps (3 failed, 24 skipped)`

```
Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/signin.feature:7 # Scenario: Navigate to Instagram Sign In
cucumber features/signin.feature:14 # Scenario: Signin with instagram credentials


7 scenarios (7 failed)
27 steps (3 failed, 24 skipped)
0m49.303s
```

some times it will be `steps (undefined, 2 passed),`or`steps (1 undefined, 2 passed, 1 failed)` or `steps (2 passed, 1 failed)`

my intention is to search the strings `failed or undefined` inside the `steps()` string.How it is possible??

Comment: so either failed or underfined present in the input string? Try `steps\s*\([^()]*(?:failed|undefined)[^()]*\)`

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*?steps\s*\((?=[^)]*(?:\bfailed\b|\bundefined\b)).*$
```

Try this.See demo.Use flag `MULTILINE`

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/52

Comment: ` var regex1 = ^.*?steps\s*\((?=[^)]*(?:\bfailed\b|\bundefined\b)).*$

      var match = regex1.exec(re);
      if (match != null) {
        isfail = match[1];
console.log( match[1])
      
      } `not working

Comment: @Psl did you apply `M` flag?